# Cache solution jaxb

Tags: spring, jaxb, jax-ws, ehcache

I have a requirement in which I need to cache data coming as response from a soap ws. I am using Spring with JAXB and JAX-WS to call the web service. I am using ehcache for caching.

What I would want ideally is that the user data for example is cached as the java bean (JAXB). We can use the id of a bean (JAXB bean) as the name. Whenever data is requested, the data should first be checked in the cache and if the data is not available, the soap ws should be called and then the data should be stored in the cache.

I am not aware if there is already a solution to handle this in spring or ehcache or maybe in JAXB. Can someone please help me out.

Comment: Check out Spring's Cache project. It'll handle this easily

Answer (score 0):

In my view, the more important point to ask would be how would you keep the server data in synch with what you have cached on the client side? If you really want to do this, then you would have to create some sort of mechanism to notify clients that the original data has updated.

For e.g. one solution could be to create a JMS Topic (Pub/Sub) and have the server publish an event to this topic. All clients listen to this topic and reload the cache by making the web service call at this point.

In terms of the cache itself at the client end, why not just choose a ConcurrentHashMap to begin with?